# Use of プラトニック in this sentence?

Tags: translation, katakana

I found this sentence from the japanese yahoo answers:

> 男性は結婚して幸せでも、初恋の女性（プラトニック）のことを忘れられないものですか？

I think the sentence means: "Even if men marry and are happy, can they just not forget their first love?"

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q134724423

But I don't understand what (プラトニック) means for this question. Does it mean the man is currently in a platonic friendship with their first love? Or does it mean they never got past a platonic friendship but were still in love??

Comment: I think it refers to the idea that one’s first love will live forever in one’s mind/heart in a platonic way. Wether this first love was “consumed” or not.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira, I suspect you mean [_consummated_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consummate) ("completed, fulfilled"), not [_consumed_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consume) ("eaten, destroyed, used up").  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the definition from 大辞林, via [the entry page at Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%88%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF):

> 純粋に精神的なさま。特に、恋愛において、**肉欲を伴わず純粋に相手を思うさま**。 「 －な愛」

(Emphasis mine.)

There's nothing about being in a platonic friendship.  Nor is there anything about physical passion.

I'd suggest the following translation.

> Even if men get married and are happy, it's that they can't forget their first love (on a platonic level)?

The "platonic" here is meant to convey that the men in question aren't horndogs lusting after their first loves, but rather that they still feel some emotional connection to that person (regardless of whether that person feels anything back towards them).

Comment: As ever, @Downvoters, please comment to explain what you disagree with, or what you think is missing.